# After submitting a form to javascript and receiving result , another value cannot be submitted without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, html

I wrote a javascript code to find nth prime number, though not efficient it do give the result. However after submitting the value and getting result for first time, i can submit another value on the same page again but i won't get result.

```html
<html>
<head><title>test</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function prime(n){
 if(n==1)
  window.alert("2");
 else if(n==2)
  window.alert("3");
 else{

 var arr=[];
 prime=2;
 while((arr.length)!=n)
 {
  count=0;
 for(i=2;i<prime;i++)
 {
  if((prime%i)==0)
  count=count+1;
 }

 if(count<=0)
  arr.push(prime);

 prime++;
 }
 num=arr.pop();
 window.alert(num);
 }
}
</script>
<body>
<form name="frm">
 <input type="text" name="n" id="id1">
    <input type="button" value="find" onclick="prime(document.frm.n.value)" >
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're assigning to `prime` within your function, but you haven't declared it as a local variable. So it's assigning to the function's variable instead. Add `let prime` (or `var prime` for ES5) within the function to make it local.

Your code is also falling prey to what I call [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html): You never declare `count` or `num`, so the first time you assign to them, you create globals for them.

Fundamentally: Declare your variables in the scope where you need them (in this case, within the `prime` function).